# Show open-source elements as ending on the last contribution date

Tags: feature-request, bug, developer-story, user-experience

I have a lot of old open-source projects showing near the top of my 'story' that I haven't even looked at in years. It would make sense to end them at the time of my last commit so that they are ordered properly.

Comment: There's a general problem with ordering. If you look at my Story, you'll see certifications or courses from 2010 appearing above a job that started in 2011.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We're currently looking into improved ordering of items and will be able to provide an update soon.